# Unexpected call when using function in simple driver

Tags: c, function, call

I am testing function 'min', which returns smaller of two `double` values, in own driver.

Output should be as follows:
**Please enter FIRST double value:

...

Please enter SECOND double value:

...**
but I receive preceding messages in reverse order. What is the correct explanation for this issue?
Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

double min(double x, double y) { return x < y ? x : y; }
void set_response(bool *);
double get_double(int);

int main(void)
{
    bool quit = false;

    printf("-----This is the driver for evaluation of \'min\' function.-----\n");
    printf("-----Enter string not beginning with \'q\' to continue.____-----\n");
    printf("-----Enter string beginning with \'q\' to quit.____________-----\n");

    while (set_response(&quit), !quit)
        printf("Result of \'min\' function is: %f\n", min(get_double(1), get_double(2))), getchar();

    printf("Thanks for efforts, dude!\n");

    return 0;
}

void set_response(bool * resp)
{
    if (getchar() == 'q')
        *resp = true;
    else
        *resp = false, scanf("%*s");
}

double get_double(int order)
{
    printf("Please enter %s double value:\n", order == 1 ? "FIRST" : "SECOND");
    double val;
    while (scanf("%lf", &val) != 1)
    {
        scanf("%*s");
        printf("Please enter %s correct double value:\n", order == 1 ? "FIRST" : "SECOND");
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Order of evaluation of parameters is not guaranteed in C. Only by using an intermediate sequence point (eg: && or || etc) can you make it so.

Comment: I could swear I knew the arguments of the comma operator are evaluated from left to right then the rightmost one is used as the result. You have my attention.

Comment: Ah! But a function call f(a,b,c) is not a use of the comma operator! The order of evaluation for a, b, and c is unspecified. I remember this from the C faq - I'll see can I find it and reference it.

Comment: Found it: http://c-faq.com/.xx/expr/comma.html. And for total citational completedness: K&R2 Sec. 3.5 p. 63. :-)

Comment: @carveone Thanks for answer and linking interesting resource!

Answer (score 3):

```
min(get_double(1), get_double(2))
```

is a function call, so the order of evaluation of its parameters is not guaranteed to be first `get_double(1)` and second `get_double(2)`

An workaround may be:

```
double x1 = get_double(1);
double x2 = get_double(2);
```

and then use x1 and x2 as parameters in the function call:

```
min(x1, x2)
```

Comment: Yep - similarly for expressions like a() + b(). See: http://c-faq.com/.xx/expr/comma.html.

Answer (score 0):

follow the axiom:

```
*only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
```

the order of the parameter evaluation in this line:

```
printf("Result of \'min\' function is: %f\n", min(get_double(1), get_double(2)));
getchar();
```

is from right to left because the parameters are pushed onto the stack from right to left.

Strongly suggest removing all the 'clever' (but does not work as expected)  stuff from your code.

In this case, do the two calls to `get_double()` and save the results, then call the `printf()` function.